# Catching exception so the app doesn't crash, but having the exception appear in the developer console

Tags: android

I have a crash in my app that I can't reproduce but a few of my users can. I can wrap the code in a try...catch block to stop the app from crashing, but I'd love to have the exceptions appear in my developer console so I can fix the bug properly.

Is there some built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the logger:

http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/16/android-activity-life-cyclelogcat-and-exception-handling/

Comment: That won't upload the exception to the developer console online when the user has the exception happen.